# Can't remove Access Point setting

Tags: wireless, ap-hotspot

I once set up an Access Point called Test on my computer and I don't need it anymore. Every time I start the computer, the AP is working by default, and I can't connect to the Internet before I turn this AP down.

And when I open 'Network Connections', I can't find this AP there. In other words, I don't know how to delete this AP setting.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Wireless LAN card information from 'sudo lshw -class network':

```
>   *-network               
>        description: Wireless interface
>        product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>        vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>        logical name: wlp2s0
>        version: 32
>        serial: f8:da:0c:3d:61:5d
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-96-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1
> ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE
> 802.11abgn
>        resources: irq:132 memory:ef200000-ef3fffff
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using so that we might better help in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: Did you create the Hotspot with Network Manager or with something else?